# Prevent redirect from being added to history

Tags: html, forms, redirect, browser-history

I have a server side rendered website. A typical user journey for submitting a form might be:

1. from /interesting-page navigate to /form
2. enter data into form on /form page and hit submit
3. server recieved form data, stores it, and redirects to /form (so that the user can submit more data if they wish) but the html is different this time because it includes a message stating the data that was submitted.
4. user submits another form and the same thing happens, they are redirected to a blank form with a message stating the data that was previously submitted.
5. user decides they want to return to /interesting-page so they hit back once and are taken to /form with the previous form data repopulated, but the html still has data from the previous submit, they hit back again and are taken to /form with the first data, but again the same html. They hit back again and are finally taken back to /interesting-page.

Having to press back 3 times is arguably not the best user experience but at least it makes some sense to the user since they can see they are being taken back through the form data they submitted. When it wouldn't make sense is when the form has no data and is just a submit button, eg it is just incrementing some value. In this case when the user presses back the pages they see are identical - the html is the same and there is no old form data to be shown. This is obviously a terrible user experience. The obvious solution in this case is to simply use javascript fetch to submit the data, avoiding a redirect. However, this means I would also need to make and document updates that would have happened server side during the redirect, client side instead, which significantly increases the complexity of my server side rendered app. Are there any better alternatives that allow me to continue to use html forms and server side document udpates, without adding the redirects to the browser history?